# Access SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have enherited an `Access`-database with some queries. It is an account-database with information on the different accounts. Specifically IBAN-numbers for each account.

One of the queries is this, where we compare IBAN-numbers from the database with IBAN-numbers from the imported `Id`-table:

```
SELECT CAMTaccounts.IBAN, CAMTaccounts.Comment
FROM CAMTaccounts LEFT JOIN Id ON CAMTaccounts.[IBAN] = Id.[IBAN]
WHERE (((Id.IBAN) Is Null));
```

I thought I understood the `SQL`-language to some degree coming from SQL Server, but this statement, I cannot understand.

To me, this is equivalent to writing:

```
Select CAMTaccounts.*
From CAMTaccounts Left Outer Join Id On CAMTaccounts.IBAN = Id.IBAN
Where Id.IBAN Is Null
```

and this join, to me, does not make any sense.

But clearly, I am not understanding this correctly.
I was hoping, that some of you could explain my flawed logic to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you think it doesnt make sense?

Comment: Because we join on = Id.IBAN and afterwards specify that Id.IBAN should be Null, which it never is and therefore the join is redundant. We only get data from the left table CAMTaccounts, but no data from the right Id-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return all rows from `CAMTaccounts` which have no matching `Id` rows. This is known as Anti-join query. Excessive parenthesis really make no sense, most probably generated with a tool.

Comment: Yes, I think it is generated with Query Designer in Access.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `CAMTaccounts.IBAN` have values

```
A
B
```

And `Id.IBAN` have values

```
B
C
```

Then this query WITHOUT `WHERE` clause outputs something like this

```
`CAMTaccounts.IBAN` | `Id.IBAN`
 ---------------------------------
 A                  | NULL
 B                  | B
```

You can easily see what will result from this, if add `Where Id.IBAN Is Null` clause.

So, this query will give you result from `CAMTaccounts` table, when `IBAN` column doesn't contains value from `Id.IBAN` column

Comment: Thanks, both Oto and Serg for the answers.